# why SharePoint 2013 takes too much time to authenticate for both windows and forms authentication for the first time?

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sts-securitytokenservice, fba

I have made a SharePoint 2013 internet site, it's works fine and loads quickly
but when i login for the first time ,it takes about 30 second to authenticate for both windows and forms

i have traced the following forms authntication code

```
   private static bool EstablishSessionWithToken(SecurityToken securityToken)
    {
        if (null == securityToken)
        {
            return false;
        }

        SPFederationAuthenticationModule fam = SPFederationAuthenticationModule.Current;

        if (null == fam)
        {
            return false;
        }

        fam.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(securityToken, SPSessionTokenWriteType.WritePersistentCookie);

        return true;
    }
```

no exception occurred but  specfically it takes 30 seconds at this line

```
  fam.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(securityToken, SPSessionTokenWriteType.WritePersistentCookie);
```

after i login successfully ,the next login will be fine and quickly
this problem happened again after one hour or more

i have checked the share point LOGS files but couldn't find any information related to that

Comment: Keep distributed cache service on. it helps in caching security token resulting in faster response.

Comment: it's already opened ....but i discovered that one of two front end server works fine but the other takes 30 second to authenticate .